# maya2008 win32api 64 bit python

Tags: python, maya

How is it possible to run `import win32api` successfully on a 64bit maya version 2008?

The following error occurs:

```
Error: No module named win32api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

I need to get mouse cursor position in python so that I can place window exactly in that position. Is there any other way to get it?

Best regards,

kNish

Comment: Trying to rule out the obvious:  You have installed the 64-bit Python for Windows extensions from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ right?

Comment: correct me iiaw
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/
suggests pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.6.exe. This py2.6 is for maya2009 not 2008. i need pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.5.exe ( 64bit, py2.5 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maya uses its own Python installation. You need to add the path where pywin32 is installed by one way or another ... you can create a .pth file in

> C:\Program
>   Files\Autodesk\Maya2009\Python\Lib\site-packages\

Also, like Adam pointed out, make sure you have the 64 bit pywin32 installed.

Here's an article talking about this subject:

http://www.rtrowbridge.com/blog/2008/11/27/maya-python-import-scripts/

Edit:

Yeah indeed I think they don't provide PyWin32 for Python25 x64:

> Available for AMD64 versions of
>   Windows for Python 2.6 and later
>   (support   for Python 2.5 is just too
>   hard, sorry).  Lots of help from
>   Roger,    Steve Yin and Sidnei da
>   Silva.

http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=603349

Comment: so if i do not find pywin32 for amd64 and py2.5 is there a way to compile it